# Compile using variable names in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to write a bash script that automates an install (I know, I know, I should be using `make`), and it's intended to be generic: supporting different compilers and build flags.

For instance, I have these lines:

```
$FORTRAN_COMPILER $LINKERFLAGS lagrit_main.o lagrit_main.f
$FORTRAN_COMPILER $LINKERFLAGS lagrit_fdate.o lagrit_fdate.f
make $MAKEFLAG lib
$FORTRAN_COMPILER $BUILDFLAGS $LAGRIT_NAME $BUILDLIBS $BUILDSUFFIX
```

with the variables set as

```
FORTRAN_COMPILER=gfortran
LINKERFLAGS="-O -fcray-pointer -fdefault-integer-8 -m64 -Dlinx64 -c -o"
BUILDFLAGS="-O -Dlinx64 -fcray-pointer -fdefault-integer-8 -fno-sign-zero -o"
BUILDLIBS="lagrit_main.o lagrit_fdate.o lagrit_ulin64_o_gcc.a $LAGRIT_UTIL_DIR/util_ulin64_o_gcc.a"
BUILDSUFFIX="-L$ACCESS -lexodus -lexoIIv2for -lnetcdf -lm -lstdc++"
MAKEFLAG="MOPT=64"
```

Which returns these errors:

```
 gfortran: error: lagrit_main.o: No such file or directory
 gfortran: error: lagrit_fdate.o: No such file or directory

 gfortran: error: lagrit: No such file or directory
 gfortran: error: lagrit_main.o lagrit_fdate.o  lagrit_ulin64_o_gcc.a /scratch/sft/livingston/build/shared/LaGriT/lg_util/src/util_ulin64_o_gcc.a: No such file or directory
```

But, when I run the same commands in long-form (i.e., `gfortran -O  -fcray-pointer -fdefault-integer-8 -m64 -Dlinx64 -c -o lagrit_main.o lagrit_main.f`) it builds with no problem.

What am I missing here? I've tried different permutations of the variable lines, including:

```
gfortran $LINKERFLAGS lagrit_main.o lagrit_main.f
"$FORTRAN_COMPILER" "$LINKER_FLAGS" lagrit_main.o lagrit_main.f
${FORTRAN_COMPILER} ${LINKER_FLAGS} lagrit_main.o lagrit_main.f
```

which all result in the same error.

**EDIT**: For clarification, this is on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Are all variables declared in the same Bash script? If not, you may be missing an `export VAR`...

Comment: They are; in fact, I've done an `echo "$FORTRAN_COMPILER $BUILDFLAGS $LAGRIT_NAME $BUILDLIBS $BUILDSUFFIX"` (along with the other two lines) and the output matches exactly what the hard-coded `gfortran` command is.

Comment: if you move the -o out of the variable and into the final call line, does the issue resolve?

Comment: Because quoting prohibits word splitting, you should not quote `XXX_FLAGS` like `"$LINKER_FLAGS"`. And you can check really excuted command with `set -x` or `#!/bin/bash -x`.

Comment: After adding `#!/bin/bash -x`, I found that the terminal is interpreting the Fortran line as: `gfortran '-O  -fcray-pointer -fdefault-integer-8 -m64 -Dlinx64 -c -o' lagrit_main.o lagrit_main.f`. The single quotes indicate the flags are being passed as a string to gfortran, which it has no idea what to do with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this command is run:

```
$FORTRAN_COMPILER $LINKERFLAGS lagrit_main.o lagrit_main.f
```

It is parsed by the terminal like this:

```
gfortran '-O -fcray-pointer -fdefault-integer-8 -m64 -Dlinx64 -c -o' lagrit_main.o lagrit_main.f
```

You can see that the linker flags are interpreted as a string, and passed to gfortran as a string. This is the root of the error.

The solution is to instead define the linker flags as an array, with each argument an element in this array:

```
LINKERFLAGS=(-O  -fcray-pointer -fdefault-integer-8 -m64 -Dlinx64 -c -o)
$FORTRAN_COMPILER ${LINKERFLAGS[*]} lagrit_main.o lagrit_main.f || exit 1
```

Comment: In every shell I have every encountered, word-splitting occurs and $FORTRAN_COMPILER $LINKERFLAGS passes the components of $LINKERFLAGS to $FORTRAN_COMPILER as individual arguments.  If this is the actual solution, which version of which shell is being used?

Comment: I typically encounter the same thing. But this script, for whatever reason, doesn't behave this way. I've run it on bash 4.3.46 (Ubuntu 16.04) and zsh 5.2 w/ bash 3.2.57 (macOS Sierra). Others using this script in different environments have reported the same thing.